# Can Emotion pass it’s Component name as a className?

Tags: emotion

When I create a styled component, the final html has some hash as its className. I understand why.

Is there some kind of way to have 
`const LovelyDiv = styled.div({ styles })` render as `<div class=“LovelyDiv-csfgte”>` (where `csfgte` is whatever random hash emotion would already create)?

It seems odd to me that they don’t already do this. Seems like a no brainer.